# Remove String from MD-CHIPS input after paste

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I am using md-chips and created a helper method for dealing with copy paste. My method triggers on ng-paste and converts a string of elements (separated by comma) in to individual chips. so far so good. however after the conversion I have the new chips + the original pasted string in the input field. My question now is, how can I remove the string?

My on-paste method basically parses the input and adds the results to the list to which chips is bound(ng-model)

Thanks for your help
Benedict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I also had an autocomplete for chip creation. The solution was to empty md-search-text.